# Typescript ts-loader symlink via lerna yarn workspace failed to resolve dependencies outside of current workspace

Tags: typescript, webpack, lerna, yarn-workspaces, ts-loader

I have a monorepo with specific structure. I am trying to migrate from gulp-typescript to webpack ts-loader. But it appears to be unable to resolve modules which are in monorepo root. I get many errors of the kind
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\msi4\monorepo\node_modules\nats\lib'` when building one of the projects in apps. Works with gulp or tsc, but not with webpack.

Project structure:

```
package.json
lerna.json
/node_modules 
/apps
  /project_a
    /node_modules
    webpack.config.js
    tsconfig.json
    package.json
  /project_b
    /node_modules
    webpack.config.js
    tsconfig.json
    package.json
/lib
  /package_a
    /node_modules
    webpack.config.js
    tsconfig.json
    package.json
  /package_b
    /node_modules
    webpack.config.js
    tsconfig.json
    package.json
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "baseUrl": "src",

    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "composite": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "allowJs": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "definitions"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

const { NODE_ENV = "development" } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: path.join(__dirname, "src/main.ts"),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "main.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      /* TS file loader */
      {
        test: /\.ts|\.tsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,

        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      "*",
      ".ts",
      ".tsx",
      ".mjs",
      ".js",
      ".json",
      ".json",
      ".gql",
      ".graphql",
    ],
    symlinks: false,
  },

  mode: NODE_ENV,
};
```

Tried setting symlinks to false as per [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvesymlinks). How can i configure webpack to understand monorepo modules ?